# kvm guest reboots into centos 7 emergency mode after extending xfs with a second drive

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, xfs

I have a host server running Centos 7 and KVM for virtualization.

I created a guest also running Centos 7, and it works perfectly.

However because my host server does not have a lot of space left on the drive, I added a second drive, on the host machine i typed `virsh attach-disk centos7.0 /dev/sdb1 vdb` and now on my guest server, i can see the second new drive.

Now to add this new drive to the `/` mount for `/dev/centos/root` I did the following:

```
pvcreate /dev/vdb<BR>
vgextend centos /dev/vdb
lvextend -L+250G /dev/centos/root
yum install xfsprogs.x86_64 --assumeyes
xfs_growfs /dev/centos/root
```

Note:

- My LV is called centos
- I have to use this xfs, as centos 7 uses xfs and not ext3 or 4

Everything worked great, i had 250 extra gb of space for my / mount.
I rebooted the guest server and it still worked great!

However as soon as i rebooted the host server and tried to boot into the guest server, the server boots into emergency mode with the following error:

```
buffer i/o error on device dm-2 logical block 73145654
```

any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: did you check that both vda and vdb are still accessible by the VM? What disk caching options do you use? Why extend with a second disk at all, when you can make vda larger instead?